# How to correct permissions for CPackDeb directories?

Tags: cmake, file-permissions, packaging, deb, cpack

Given a `CMakeLists.txt` like:

```
PROJECT(asdf NONE)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.0)

INSTALL(FILES CMakeLists.txt DESTINATION share/doc/asdf/whatever)

SET(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT "asdf@example.com")
INCLUDE(CPack)
```

The package generated by `make package` has following contents:

```
$ dpkg-deb --contents asdf-0.1.1-Linux.deb 
drwx------ root/root         0 2017-12-20 10:50 ./usr/
drwx------ root/root         0 2017-12-20 10:50 ./usr/share/
drwx------ root/root         0 2017-12-20 10:50 ./usr/share/doc/
drwx------ root/root         0 2017-12-20 10:50 ./usr/share/doc/asdf/
drwx------ root/root         0 2017-12-20 10:50 ./usr/share/doc/asdf/whatever/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       235 2017-12-20 10:50 ./usr/share/doc/asdf/whatever/CMakeLists.txt
```

with the parent directories having only permission bits for the owner. How do I correct these so that the world could read the files I install, e.g. for these to be something like `drwxr-xr-x` instead?

Answer (score 1):

In a discussion with CMake developer Nils Gladitz we were able to track this issue down the umask of the environment affecting this. If the umask in the environment is set to `0022` instead of `0077`, then `make package` generates the package with different permissions:

```
$ dpkg-deb --contents asdf-0.1.1-Linux.deb 
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2017-12-20 11:17 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2017-12-20 11:17 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2017-12-20 11:17 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2017-12-20 11:17 ./usr/share/doc/asdf/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2017-12-20 11:17 ./usr/share/doc/asdf/whatever/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       235 2017-12-20 10:50 ./usr/share/doc/asdf/whatever/CMakeLists.txt
```

Nils noted that this is apparently an old unfixed issue<sup>[[1]](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15163)[[2]](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15163)</sup>.

Thank you, Nils! =)